# Программно создать часть xml и вставить в другой xml

Tags: java, android, xml, view

По нажатию кнопки должен добавляться card view в котором linear layout, в котором nested scroll, в котором coordinator layout.
Когда программно создаю card view и вставляю его через addview в linear layout, т.e addview(linear_layout) проект выдает ошибку и просит удалить (removeView) родителя дочернего элемента.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Информация в интернете какая-то смазанная и её мало, что делать не понимаю.. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее благодарен

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:strokeColor="#565656"
            app:strokeWidth="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/outputWindow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/result_name"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Добавить в

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

программно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делал немножко неправильно. По сути я добавлял объект в тот же объект, то есть "Петю" в "Петю". А нужно объявить через R.id "Катю", также объявить "Петю" через =new Петя(this) и через Катя.addview(Петя) вставить Петю в Катю